# Can't pass over to another page after logging in to site & It also won't let me log in after filling out the registration form

Tags: php, mysql, forms, authentication, registration

My site won't let me log into it after filling out the registration form, everything in the database is correct but it just wont let me log in! Also if I do sort out the logging in problem will it let me pass over to 'home.php'? Sorry for being such a novice and thank you for your time in advance!

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION["userlogin"])){
}else{
    $username = $_SESSION["userlogin"]; 
}
?>
<?php
$reg = @$_POST['reg'];
//declaring variables to prevent errors
$first_name = ""; //First Name
$last_name = ""; //Last Name
$username = ""; //Username
$email = ""; //Email
$email2 = ""; //Email 2
$password = ""; //Password
$password2 = ""; // Password 2
$signupdate = ""; // Sign up Date
$usercheck = ""; // Check if username exists
//registration form
$first_name = strip_tags(@$_POST['first_name']);
$last_name = strip_tags(@$_POST['last_name']);
$username = strip_tags(@$_POST['username']);
$email = strip_tags(@$_POST['email']);
$email2 = strip_tags(@$_POST['email2']);
$password = strip_tags(@$_POST['password']);
$password2 = strip_tags(@$_POST['password2']);
$signupdate = date("Y-m-d"); // Year - Month - Day

if ($reg) {
    if ($email==$email2) {
    // Check if user already exists
    $usercheck = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM users WHERE     username='$username'");
    // Count the amount of rows where username = $un
    $check = mysql_num_rows($usercheck);
    //Check whether Email already exists in the database
    $echeck = mysql_query("SELECT email FROM users WHERE email='$email'");
    //Count the number of rows returned
    $emailcheck = mysql_num_rows($echeck);
    if ($check == 0) {
        if ($emailcheck == 0) {
            //check all of the fields have been filed in
            if ($username && $first_name && $last_name && 
                $email && $email2 && $password && $password2) 
            {
                // check that passwords match
                if ($password==$password2) {
                    // check the maximum length of username/first name/last name does not exceed 25 characters
                    if (strlen($username)>25 || 
                        strlen($first_name)>25 || 
                        strlen($last_name)>25) 
                    {
                        echo "The maximum limit for username/first name/last name is 25 characters!";
                    }else {
                        // check the maximum length of password does not exceed 25 characters and is not less than 5 characters
                        if (strlen($password)>30||strlen($password)<5) {
                            echo "Your password must be between 5 and 30 characters long!";
                        }else {
                            //encrypt password and password 2 using crypt before sending to database
                            $password = crypt($password);
                            $password2 = crypt($password2);
                            $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users VALUES     ('','$username','$first_name','$last_name','$email','$password','$signupdate','0')");
                            header("Location: index.php");
                            exit;
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    echo "Your passwords don't match!";
                }
            } else {
                echo "Please fill in all of the fields";
            }
        }else{
            echo "Sorry, but it looks like someone has already used that email!";
        }
    }else{
        echo "Username already taken ...";
    }
}else {
    echo "Your E-mails don't match!";
}
}
?>
<?php
//Login Script
if (isset($_POST["userlogin"]) && isset($_POST["passwordlogin"])) {
    $userlogin = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i', '', $_POST["userlogin"]);     // filter everything but numbers and letters
    $passwordlogin = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i', '',         $_POST["passwordlogin"]); // filter everything but numbers and letters
    $cryptpasswordlogin = crypt($passwordlogin);
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE username='$userlogin' AND     password='$cryptpasswordlogin' LIMIT 1"); // query the person
    //Check for their existance
    $userCount = mysql_num_rows($sql);
    echo mysql_error();
    //Count the number of rows returned
    if ($userCount == 1) {
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){ 
             $id = $row["id"];
    }
         $_SESSION["userlogin"] = $userlogin;
        header("home.php");
        exit();
    }else{
        echo 'That information is incorrect, try again';
        exit();
    }
}
?>
<div>
            <h2>Already a Memeber? Login below ...</h2>
          <form action="index.php" method="post" name="form1" id="form1">
                <input type="text" size="40" name="userlogin" id="user_login" class="auto-clear" placeholder="Username..." /><p />
                <input type="text" size="40" name="passwordlogin"     id="password_login" placeholder="Password..." /><p />
                <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Login to your account">
            </form>
            </div>
           <div>
            <h2>Sign up Below ...</h2>
           <form action="#.php" method="post">
           <input type="text" size="40" name="username" class="auto-clear" title="Username" placeholder="Username..."><p />
           <input type="text" size="40" name="first_name"  class="auto-clear" title="First Name" placeholder="First name..."><p />
           <input type="text" size="40" name="last_name" class="auto-clear" title="Last Name" placeholder="Last name..."><p />
           <input type="text" size="40" name="email" class="auto-clear" title="Email" placeholder="Email..."><p />
           <input type="text" size="40" name="email2" class="auto-clear" title="Repeat Email" placeholder="Email again..."><p />
           <input type="password" size="40" name="password" placeholder="Password..."><p />
           <input type="password" size="40" name="password2" placeholder="Password again..."><p />
           <input type="submit" name="reg" value="Sign Up!">
           </form>
           </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Using the `@` error silencer on everything like that is very bad practice

Comment: Some sensible code indentation would be a good idea. It helps us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: Please dont __roll your own__ password hashing. PHP provides [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)
and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) please use them.
And here are some [good ideas about passwords](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet)
If you are using a PHP version prior to 5.5 [there is a compatibility pack available here](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat)

Comment: See the not in the [crypt() manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php)

Comment: Why are you doing `$password2 = crypt($password2);`

Answer (score 1):

Please note in this simple test. Using `crypt()` twice on the same string will not generate the same result.

```
echo crypt('password') . PHP_EOL;
echo crypt('password') . PHP_EOL;
```

Results are :

```
$1$5u1.o45.$QqFY/BeCcln/LO7efiDp61
$1$R55.G3..$LQ9HxetMhV3KmJYM2q8UR/
```

So when you use `crypt()` to HASH the password on registration, and then again when you try the login part of your script, even if the user enters the correct password it will **NOT** generate the same HASH therefore this query will not find the user row

```
SELECT id 
FROM users 
WHERE username='$userlogin' 
  AND password='$cryptpasswordlogin' 
LIMIT 1
```

i.e. `crypt()` will not generated the same HASH twice from the same string.

> Please dont **roll your own** password hashing. PHP provides [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)
>   and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) please use them.
>   And here are some [good ideas about passwords](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet)
>   If you are using a PHP version prior to 5.5 [there is a compatibility pack available here](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat)